# initializing array adapter and listarray error null pointer

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I don't understand what is happening

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l=null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        place = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.place);
        aa=new ArrayAdapter<String(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,l.get(0) );
        place.setAdapter(aa);
    }
}
```

But creating the new ArrayAdapter instance is causing runtime error due to `java.lang.NullPointerExeption`. I don't understand why and how can I fix this  :-/

Comment: Your adapter ArrayList  is null before given to adapter please initialize this variable.

Comment: you defined ArrayList but you didn't initialized it so you are getting NPE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `l.get(0)` is throwing NPE. You need to initialise `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l` like,

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: @Illegal Argument and you are both correct, I was reading more and I discovered how initialize one-dimension ArrayList using the double brace initialization method. Now, how it must be done for double-dimension ArrayList?

Comment: Did you try my answer?? Try `l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` and let me know.

Comment: @JoeCoolman Thanks for the accept :). You can up vote also. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this line:

```
aa=new ArrayAdapter<String(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,l.get(0) );
```

Here use of l.get(0) is null as l is never initialized.

Comment: ok, in the line before that I put l.get(0).add(""), I think "I added an empty string as first element in the l.get(0) string array" but again, now this line is causing java.lang null pointer exception.

Comment: @JoeCoolman l is null so any operation on l will result in nullpointer exception ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(); this kind of initialization needs to be done first on most of the objects including arraylist